# To show only file name without the entire directory path

Tags: shell, unix, directory, ls

`ls /home/user/new/*.txt` prints all txt files in that directory. However it prints the output as follows:

```
[me@comp]$ ls /home/user/new/*.txt
/home/user/new/file1.txt    /home/user/new/file2.txt    /home/user/new/file3.txt
```

and so on.

I want to run the `ls` command not from the `/home/user/new/` directory thus I have to give the full directory name, yet I want the output to be only as

```
[me@comp]$ ls /home/user/new/*.txt
file1.txt    file2.txt    file3.txt
```

I don't want the entire path. Only filename is needed. This issues has to be solved using ls command, as its output is meant for another program.

Comment: What OS? For example OS X does what you want already. Are you sure ls isn't aliased?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

`ls whateveryouwant | xargs -n 1 basename`

Does that work for you?

Otherwise you can `(cd /the/directory && ls)` (yes, parentheses intended)

Comment: You should probably use `ls -d` in case `whateveryouwant` refers to multiple directories.

Comment: Note that if the path contains spaces xargs will break on them. You need to use `xargs -d '\n' -n 1` instead.

Comment: This is eeeeeeextremely slow on Cygwin.

Comment: The `xargs` solution looks neater, but I found it very slow. I opted for the `cd` solution, which runs smootly.

Comment: using `xargs` was a better solution in my case, as I was giving the whole path while doing `ls` so `ls -1` didn't work in my case

Answer (score 65):

No need for Xargs and all , ls is more than enough.

```
ls -1 *.txt
```

displays row wise

Comment: This is not the correct if you read OP carefully. This only works if you are in that directory.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks @VRVigneshwara! `ls -1 bin/` list entries inside bin/ directory without path on Linux Debian.

Comment: This will cause trouble with lots (and lots) of files and also directories ending in `.txt`, and needs [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29 "glob (programming)") to be active in your shell.

Answer (score 19):

There are several ways you can achieve this. One would be something like:

```
for filepath in /path/to/dir/*
do
    filename=$(basename $filepath)

    ... whatever you want to do with the file here
done
```

Answer (score 18):

Use the `basename` command:

```
basename /home/user/new/*.txt
```

Comment: basename (GNU coreutils) 9.3 (packaged for arch linux) does not support multiple file parameters without the `-a` option. I think this applies to most(?) other versions and distros as well.

Answer (score 10):

`(cd dir && ls)`

will only output filenames in *dir*. Use `ls -1` if you want one per line.

(Changed ; to && as per Sactiw's comment).

Comment: Using ';' in place of '&&' for chaining of commands will be buggy in this case as it would return some output in case of non existing 'dir' as well i.e. list files from current working directory from where you are executing this command. 
E.g. (cd fake_dir ; ls) would list files from current directory even if no such fake_dir exists, which would be incorrect.

Answer (score 9):

you could add an sed script to your commandline:

```
ls /home/user/new/*.txt | sed -r 's/^.+\///'
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for; I was trying the "ls -1 /path/*" and wanting the path to not be listed. This nailed it !! I did not want to go the CD route in case I needed to stay in the current directory. Saved me having to note it and then return to it after the above command. Awesome.

Answer (score 8):

A fancy way to solve it is by using twice "rev" and "cut":

```
find ./ -name "*.txt" | rev | cut -d '/' -f1 | rev
```

Answer (score 6):

The selected answer did not work for me, as I had spaces, quotes and other strange characters in my filenames. To quote the input for `basename`, you should use:

```
ls /path/to/my/directory | xargs -n1 -I{} basename "{}"
```

This is guaranteed to work, regardless of what the files are called.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the base name which is already answered by fge.
Another way is :

```
ls /home/user/new/*.txt|awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'
```

one more ugly way is :

```
ls /home/user/new/*.txt| perl -pe 's/\//\n/g'|tail -1
```

Answer (score 1):

just hoping to be helpful to someone as old problems seem to come back every now and again and I always find good tips here.

My problem was to list in a text file all the names of the "*.txt" files in a certain directory without path and without extension from a Datastage 7.5 sequence.

The solution we used is:

```
ls /home/user/new/*.txt | xargs -n 1 basename | cut -d '.' -f1 > name_list.txt
```

Comment: basename can remove the suffix for you as well (you specify the suffix to remove as the second argument). your command would become: 


```ls /home/user/new/*.txt | xargs -n 1 -J % basename % .txt
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of way we can do that and simply you can try following.

```
ls /home/user/new | tr '\n' '\n' | grep .txt
```

Another method:

```
cd /home/user/new && ls *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
ls -1 /home/user/new/*.txt|rev|cut -d'/' -f1|rev
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also pipe to grep and pull everything after the last forward slash. It looks goofy, but I think a defensive grep should be fine unless (like some kind of maniac) you have forward slashes within your filenames.

```
ls folderpathwithcriteria | grep -P -o -e "[^/]*$"
```

Answer (score 0):

`find`s `-exec` argument with `basename` is perfect for this task, no need for `xargs` or subshells:

```bash
find "$path" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec basename {} \;
```

You can use `-type d` or `-type f` to filter only files or folders.

Answer (score -1):

When you want to list names in a path but they have different file extensions.

`me@server:/var/backups$ ls -1 *.zip && ls -1 *.gz`